# How can I avoid an SDK requirement for an end-user unless he uses a specific function?

Tags: c#

One of the modes of my program uses Microsoft Kinect but the user may never decide use that mode. I want to make it so the libraries for that functionality are only looked for and loaded **if** he uses that mode of the program as opposed to it throwing an error because the kinect end-user runtime library (or whatever it's called) is not installed when the program is first opened. Is that possible in C#? If so, how is that done?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853579/c-sharp-late-binding-and-dynamic-keyword-wont-work-together

Comment: [Dynamic Language Runtime Overview (msdn.microsoft.com)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this all the time on our software. All you need to do is make sure all of the references to that library are in a different class that is only ever called when the option is enabled. I *think* you also need to have your classes in a separate .cs file so that the `using` statements are also isolated. (I don't know for certain since we keep all our classes in separate files by policy.)

```
public class Application {
    public void InitOptions {
        if(optionWithThirdPartyDependency) {
            OptionalFunctionality.InitFeature();
        }
    }
}
```

In a different .cs file....

```
using ThirdPartyLibrary

public class OptionalFunctionality {
    public static void InitFeature() {
        <init the feature using ThirdPartyLibrary>
    }
}
```